# When using software RAID and LVM on Linux, which IO scheduler and readahead settings are honored?

Tags: linux, raid, lvm

In the case of multiple layers (physical drives -> md -> dm -> lvm), how do the schedulers, readahead settings, and other disk settings interact?

Imagine you have several disks (/dev/sda - /dev/sdd) all part of a software RAID device (/dev/md0) created with mdadm. Each device (including physical disks and /dev/md0) has its own setting for IO scheduler ([changed like so](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-change-io-scheduler-for-harddisk/)) and readahead ([changed using blockdev](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_blockdev.htm)). When you throw in things like dm (crypto) and LVM you add even more layers with their own settings.

For example, if the physical device has a read ahead of 128 blocks and the RAID has a readahead of 64 blocks, which is honored when I do a read from /dev/md0? Does the md driver attempt a 64 block read which the physical device driver then translates to a read of 128 blocks? Or does the RAID readahead "pass-through" to the underlying device, resulting in a 64 block read?

The same kind of question holds for schedulers? Do I have to worry about multiple layers of IO schedulers and how they interact, or does the /dev/md0 effectively override underlying schedulers?

In my attempts to answer this question, I've dug up some interesting data on schedulers and tools which might help figure this out:

- [Linux Disk Scheduler Benchmarking from Google](http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2008/08/linux-disk-scheduler-benchmarking.html)
- [blktrace - generate traces of the i/o traffic on block devices](http://linux.die.net/man/8/blktrace)
- [Relevant Linux kernel mailing list thread](http://www.spinics.net/lists/raid/msg29375.html)

Answer (score 8):

If you do a read from md0 then the readahead for md0 is used.  If you did the read from sda which is a component of md0 then it would use the sda setting.  Device mapper just splits an I/O up into multiple reads and writes to do the RAID, but that's all below the block cache layer where readahead takes place.  The storage stack looks like:

> filesystem - bypasses cache when you open with O_DIRECT
>
> block cache - readahead, write cache, scheduler
>
> device-mapper - dm, lvm, software RAID, snapshot, etc.
>
> sd - disk driver
>
> SCSI - error handling, device routing
>
> hardware driver - scsi card, FC card, ethernet

Note that when you do

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=foo
```

you are reading sda as a file, so you are going through block cache.  To go direct to the disk, do

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=foo iflag=direct
```

As for I/O elevator schedulers, those only exist on the disk driver (sd).  There is no queue directory under /sys/block/md or /sys/block/dm.  You only go through the disk elevator sort once.

Comment: There is a `/sys/block/md0/queue/scheduler` on my systems, but the only choice in there is `none`.